# Running a lengthy script on google cloud compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run a lengthy script (should take a couple of days) but the problem is when I close my computer, or even when it enters sleep mode the VM disconnects and stops the script.

How can I make it run without stopping it when I am disconnected, or how to stay connected even when my computer enters sleep mode?

Comment: Use a program like **screen** or **tmux**.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion from the comment section I found that using the screen program works easily, and here is what worked for me:

First installing screen program (Ubuntu):    `sudo apt-get install screen`. Next run the process. To detach the screen session and keep the process running use Ctrl+A then Ctrl+D. Now you can safely disconnect from SSH connection and the process continues running. To go back to the screen session use `screen -r`.